# How to view the source of a page in Firefox?

Tags: firefox

First of all, I know about Developers Tools > View Source and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>. What I'm talking about is the equivalent to Chrome/ium's `view-source:somedomain.com`, which I could see the source of a page without having to render the page itself first.

Chrome:

[image]

Firefox/Iceweasel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL in Firefox is basically the same:

```
view-source:https://www.google.com/
```

works here.